# Lipo battery doesn't charge cell no 2

Tags: lipo, lithium-polymer

I wasted a lipo battery earlier. I googled so I know that when it goes flat it is unusable. Then I bought another battery of same type 3s. After using it for a month or 2, it suddenly started showing voltage 8.5 which is supposed to be 11.1 volt. At charging the cell 1 and 2 are green, while cell 2 shows red light, means not charged. I am using it in my quad copter which is currently under making. What should I do? I opened the battery pack, the solder connections are fine. I checked separately the voltages of the 3 cells using multi meter cell 2 read 0 volt. Other one 4 volt. Any suggestion would be appreciated.[image]
Imax b3 charger

Comment: Does your LiPo charger have cell equalization connections to the battery pack?  It sounds as if the individual cells are not being charged properly.

Comment: My charger have no buttons over it. Just female header for battery insertion, and lights.

Comment: please, Post the image of your charger with the model number.

Comment: I am trying. But is the problem with the charger,

Comment: What capacity is your li-po battery?

Comment: Do you power your charger first and then connect the battery? Are you following all the [instructions](http://abc-rc.pl/templates/images/files/995/b3-pro-manual.pdf) from the very begining? In the early days did it charge the battery properly or you haven't notice the proper functioning?

Comment: 2200mah d d d f    d d d f g g f s d

Comment: I ruined it up,  i opened it up completely, there were 3 packs. two packs were showing 4volt. 1 had no voltage. I opened that pack even more but to check the connections properly, but that just ruined. I kept the two packs and throwed the other one. Time to buy another one. This time better one,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After using it for a month or 2, it suddenly started showing voltage 8.5 which is supposed to be 11.1 volt*

Lithium polymer batteries should be handled properly. Most important thing is, it should not be discharged below 3 volt per cell. This might completely damage the cell. You did not mention whether or not your charger worked for a single time. Did you conform the proper functioning of your charger? If you have another pair of 2s or 3s lithium battery, then conform your battery charger is fine to use. But I hardly doubt that. From the very begining your charger did not work properly, and you did continously use it for your flying machine. It may have happened that you don't have your low voltage cutoff set properly in the ESC which led deep discharge of your battery. It is not always necessary for lithium polymer battery to die because of deep discharge, but deep discharge might have caused damage to the Cell 2. My assumption is that you have a faulty li-po battery charger. And a Faulty cell because of the deep discharge.

**Solution**

1. Check your battery charger
2. Check your ESC setting
   (refer its manual, and properly calibrate your ESC)

Its just my assumption, Other may point out what actually had happened.  :)

Comment: I think the reason was that my quadcopter has 4esc's which takes 30amp. And battery was of 10c 2200mah means 10x2200m 22amp discharge rate. And required is 30ampx4esc's 120amp rate.

Comment: can you state the model number of your esc and its current rating?

Comment: 30amp esc esc 30amp

Comment: See [this](http://blog.oscarliang.net/how-to-choose-battery-for-quadcopter-multicopter/) I hope it has the information you need.

Comment: I have seen this already